# Sides of text boxes being cut off in VB.net WPF controls

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls

Trying to design a vb.net WPF login screen and when I run the program the sides of my Textbox controls are being cut off.

In the preview design window everything looks fine pre-run.

It seems like the grid element may be causing this but I can't seem to find any layout/margin setting for this.  I've tried to increase the overall size of the grid and that didn't work.

If I reset the margins I everything works but my elements are not in the right locations.  Something about moving them around seems to cause the behavior.

After researching online the only hint I could find was that perhaps by dragging and dropping the controls on the window it caused the problem however using the dev environment as designed shouldn't cause this behavior (I hope).

Comment: You should show your XAML, otherwise it's kinda hard to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about not posting XAML code.

I was able to get the form elements to stop chopping themselves off by removing the right margin of each text box.  Apparently when you use the GUI to move elements around it adds all four margins.